# Angular rxjs Observable.forkJoin 404

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, observable

I have a couple different service calls I need to make to build a user object.  One of the calls will not always return data as the data is optional.

I have the code below, but the code is never making it into .map function when a 404 is encountered with the optional API call.  I see it hitting the catch on the optional URL API call, but the .map is never called.  Is it possible to use the forkJoin with an API that may return a 404 response?

```
    return Observable.forkJoin([
        this.wmrk_http.get('required-url')
            .map((res:Response) => <user> res.json())
            .catch((res:Response) =>  Observable.empty<user>()),
        this.wmrk_http.get('required-url-2')
            .map((res:Response) => <groups> res.json())
            .catch((res:Response) =>  Observable.empty<groups>()),
        this.wmrk_http.get('optional-data-url')
            .map((res:Response) => <userData> res.json())
            .catch((res:Response) => Observable.empty<userData>()),     
    ])
    .map((data: any[]) => {
        ...
    });
```

Comment: Please expand on *"not working"* with a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forkJoin` [stops the chain](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2188) if one of the items doesn't emit a value. So use either use defaultIfEmpty or replace `observable.empty` with `observable.of(null)`. See [the working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1HnjeTISKbWFf4tOtvsS?p=preview)

```
    Observable.forkJoin([
        this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/karser')
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch((res:Response) =>  Observable.of(null)),
        this.http.get('https://api.github.com/fsdfsdf')
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch((res:Response) =>  Observable.of(null)),
        this.http.get('https://api.github.com/2')
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch((res:Response) => Observable.of(null))
    ])
    .map((data: any[]) => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .subscribe();
```

The output is

```
GET https://api.github.com/users/karser 200 (OK)
GET https://api.github.com/fsdfsdf 404 (Not Found)
GET https://api.github.com/2 404 (Not Found)

[Object, null, null]
```